# The system cannot find the file specified in SublimeText3 for lua build. How can I solve this?

Tags: error-handling, lua, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

How can I bring my lua build to work on SublimeText3? I downloaded Lua Love package with the Control package, but it doesn't work. It states:

```
[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
[cmd: ['lua', 'C:\\Users\\NAME\\Downloads\\lua-5.3.2\\tests\\test.lua']]
[dir: C:\Users\NAME\Downloads\lua-5.3.2\tests]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32]
[Finished]
```

'Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden' just means 'The system cannot find the file specified', but in German.

PS: I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: Is the Lua executable anywhere in your search paths? Can you call `lua -v` in your console/cmd.exe without previous commands?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Lua and include the `lua.exe`'s directory in your Windows `PATH` environment variable. The build system printed out your `PATH`, and Lua is not there. `Lua Love` only includes tools for calling the Lua compiler, not the compiler itself.